# xcode image coordinates

Tags: xcode, image, coordinate

Ok im in the middle of making a game for iphone and i was wondering how to delete an image if it gets past a certain coordinates. Im doing this strait in xcode. Also please post some example code. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

or, if you want it to come back later, just do

```
[imageView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: what i mean is if it goes past a certain area it will get deleted. for example if(image.x == 10 && image.y == 10) { Image.delete }. I know that code wouldnt be right. So how would i do this?

Comment: @Tyler: Well, if you post the relevant code for how you're moving things around, then I may be able to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a view `aView` that you are moving around through code.  Now let's say `aRect` is a rectangle where `aView` should be visible.  If `aView` moves outside of `aRect` and you want to remove it, you can do something like this:

```
.... you move aView ....
if (!CGRectContainsRect(aRect, [aView frame])) {
    [aView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I should point out that this method only works if you are moving `aView` with a timer or some such method.  Otherwise something like this is slightly less trivial.